# Is there a way to identify if the user is moving on a main road/highway or something or to a pedestrian road?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to identify if the user is moving on a main road/highway/a road that can also cars go or something or even to a pedestrian road? 
Actually i work on an android app that if the user is in a road that also cars can use then sounds an error

Answer (score 0):

GPS on a phone just isn't accurate enough to do that.  You'd need at least a meter of accuracy to tell if someone is on the sidewalk or not, more would be better.  10m is more phone GPS levels.

Comment: I agree, but if you check the map of google map you can see that there is a yellow line on a highway , how can i take that information
(thank you for your reply)